# How to initialise an instance of `ApolloClient` in nodejs?

Tags: graphql, apollo, apollo-client

I have below code written in nodejs10.

```
const ApolloClient = require('apollo-boost');

const client = new ApolloClient({
  uri: 'http://localhost:8000/graphql'
});
```

The error I got when running this program is:

```
const client = ApolloClient({
               ^

TypeError: ApolloClient is not a function
```

Below is the dependencies:

```
"apollo-boost": "^0.3.1",
    "apollo-cache-inmemory": "^1.6.0",
    "apollo-client": "^2.6.0",
    "apollo-link-http": "^1.5.14",
    "apollo-server": "^2.5.0",
    "apollo-server-express": "^2.5.1",
```

I followed the user guide to setup a apollo client to take to me server. But it failed at very beginning stage. I wonder what wrong with my code. Is there anything I missed?

Answer (score 0):

In order to initialize Apollo Client, you must specify link & cache properties on the config object. You can override this by using the default import.

```
const apollo = require('apollo-boost');
const ApolloClient = apollo.default;

const client = new ApolloClient({
  uri: 'http://localhost:8000/graphql'
});
```

Comment: I tried your approach but `DefaultClient` is undefined under `apollo-boost`. Which version are you using?

Comment: Try const apollo = require('apollo-boost').default;

Comment: I tried that but got this error `throw new ts_invariant_1.InvariantError("\nfetch is not found globally and no fetcher passed, to fix pass a fetch for\nyour environment like https://www.npmjs.com/package/" + library + ".\n\nFor example:\nimport fetch from '" + library + "';\nimport { createHttpLink } from 'apollo-link-http';\n\nconst link = createHttpLink({ uri: '/graphql', fetch: fetch });");`

Comment: Do I have to specify the link and cache? If so what point to use `apollo-boost`?

Answer (score 0):

require('apollo-boost') does **not** return ApolloClient, it returns an object that contains ApolloClient.

From a github [issue](https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-client/issues/3639) on **ApolloGraphQL/apollo-client**:

```
// es6 import
import { default as ApolloClient } from 'apollo-boost';

// es5 or Node.js
const Boost = require('apollo-boost');
const ApolloClient = Boost.DefaultClient;
```